# Medalhas não estão traduzidas no perfil

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, localização

As medalhas estão traduzidas corretamente na [lista de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), entretanto no perfil está mostrando a descrição em Inglês:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apareceram novas descrições lá no Transifex, deve ser isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Precisamente. Todo mundo de volta ao trabalho :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O novo perfil mudou um monte de strings e adicionou um monte de strings novas. Como cada elas recebe uma hash como ID, string nova - mesmo que seja igual à uma antiga - tem que ser traduzida novamente.

Localização é só alegria.

O jeito é ir ao Transifex e acertar tudo de novo.

### EDIT:

Falha minha. O que ocorre aí é bug técnico mesmo. As traduções estão todas corretas.

Comment: Fechado! Lá vamos nós.

Comment: Então toda vez que mudarem qualquer detalhe numa string traduzida precisaremos retraduzi-la toda, e ainda sem saber nada sobre a versão anterior? Só eu é que acho um erro usar a string em inglês como chave no dicionário de tradução?!

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu nunca trabalhei com localização enquanto era dev, então não faço ideia de quais são as alternativas, ou como funciona especificamente em C#. Só sei que, sim, qualquer mudança requer uma nova tradução.

Comment: @bfavaretto bem observado, parece massante ficar traduzindo coisas já traduzidas :/

Comment: Resolvi postar essa dúvida como pergunta no site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64589/dicion%C3%A1rios-de-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-devem-usar-as-strings-originais-como-chaves (C/C @Math).

Comment: @bfavaretto legal :)